# Android platform showing black screen

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am creating a Simple Hello World Application on Android , - eclipse(Luna)

here are the setting what I have applied by looking at the existing solutions present here!
[image: Creating New Project]

[image: SDK]
[image: Device setting manager]

[image: Still is shows the black output]

[image: and here are few console Error]

I have read many posts related to these issue , 
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

your project has been set up with target sdk api 21 and compile with sdk 22 whereas your avd is api 8. try with a higher version of api for avd and also  just delete(uninstall) the package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) if it's installed. (No need to uninstall whole 5.1.1 package). May be there is some eclipse bug with this package.

Comment: I Tried with following : 1.try with a higher version of api for avd                    2. delete(uninstall) the package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) ...still same results

Comment: try uninstalling all the system images from Android 5.1.1

Comment: I did that too .Still No Luck

Comment: When I remove system images , then I am am not able to set Android device for Android 5.1.1